# Div динамическое изменение

Tags: javascript, html

Помогите,  со скриптом, который бы менял содержимое главного div'a каждые n секунд.

Допустим, есть `<div class="a"> <img src="href"> <p>text</p> <div>`

и у меня есть несколько таких блоков, все тоже с классом а, но у них разные значения href и text. Пробовал с innerHtml, не получалось

Comment: Что именно не получилось? Покажите код ваших попыток.

Comment: Каждый n секунд менял на что, не понятно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить такой вариант решения Вашей проблемы
**HTML**

```
<div class="text">
    <div class="a"><img src="href"> <p>text</p> </div>
    <div class="a"><img src="href"> <p>text</p> </div>
    <div class="a"><img src="href"> <p>text</p> </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.text .a').eq(0).addClass('active').fadeIn(1000);// Показываем первый блок, можно и не первый, если прописать нужную цифру в eq()
    setInterval('blockAnimate();', 5000);// Вызываем функцию для смены блока каждые 5 секунд
});

// Функция для смены блоков, показывает блоки по очереди, начальный блок задаётся выше
function blockAnimate() {
    var length = $('.text .a').length - 1;
    $('.text .a').each(function(index) {
        if($(this).hasClass('active') && index != length) {
            $(this).removeClass('active').fadeOut(1000).next('.a').addClass('active').fadeIn(1000);
            return false;
        } else if (index == length) {
            $(this).removeClass('active').fadeOut(1000);
            $('.text .a').eq(0).addClass('active').fadeIn(1000);
            return false;
        }
    });
};
```

**CSS**

```
.a {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;    
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось!

Comment: у меня только почему-то показывает сразу все блоки, а потом они уже по очереди появляются

Comment: и когда потом добавляется новый элемент, он попадает в конец документа, потом удаляется первый и потом только на первое место вставляется

Comment: @Apemother Действительно, забыл указать, что в CSS нужно добавить еще описание, тогда все должно работать правильно. Добавил в ответ необходимый код.

Answer (score 1):

1. Я бы назначил этому элементу  атрибут id, чтобы можно было до него быстро добраться.
2. Если надо что-то делать каждые сколько-то секунд, надо использовать таймеры, например, сетинтервал.
3. Надо писать innerHTML, а не innerHtml.

У меня получается с innerHTML.